# Solr incorrect aggregation

Tags: solr

Solr aggregation sum displays a very high precisioned value for a field only when a value 'v1' which has values like 0.18 is summed up with value 'v2' which has negative values like '-14.13'.

The correct answer should be -13.95.

But it gives -13.9500000000000000001.

Answer (score 1):

doubles in Java are only approximations. With limited space, you will always be able to find cases where there are rounding errors. If you run the code `System.out.println("Double sum: " + (0.18d + -14.13d));`, you will get the same result as Solr delivers: -13.950000000000001.

It could be remedied or at least improved by using BigDecimal or similar inside of Solr, but that would be at a very high cost of both space and speed. When you work with floating points, it is standard practice to allow for minor discrepancies. Both when comparing numbers and writing them out.

Comment: But this discrepancy when aggregated with some more values result in values like 2.733E89 (basically exponential values) which is causing more problems in the UI

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the problem you are trying to describe. The inherent impreciseness in simple floating point operations normally don't lead to wrong magnitudes.